# returnKeyLabel not working on Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am using returnKeyLabel on a flex TextInpout but it is not working. It doesn't shows up what I set. Any idea what might be the issue? Do I need to set any special skinclass for this? I am testing on iOS devices and using TextInput component

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a better researched answer for you.

What are you trying to set the returnKeyLabel to? The only valid values for it are default, done, go, next, and search. Though you can change the Label text, you cant change the label value.

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c1946f5fc1331cccb58f-8000

Note the line "Not all devices support setting the label of the return key".

Comment: I am testing this on iPod Touch 4th generation and using the specified returnKeyLabel string values like: next, go etc. Not changing the label text.